# How to specify $HOME folder on visual studio code debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, path, visual-studio-code

In our team, we use visual studio code (macOS, linux) for nodejs debugging. 
As we work with several version of node, we need to specify the runtimeExecutable path in launch.json file. That works well.

However, we need to automate the generation of this file (launch.json), and for that we need to specify the home folder (~). Does someone know how to specify it ? I tryed ~, $HOME, ${HOME}, but none of these seems to work.

Thank you,

Alcyon

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `${env:HOME}`. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution for a list of the allowed substitution vars, and how they work.

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you very much. Your page will be helpful for us for the rest.

Comment: FYI they've deprecated the dot notation. It would now be `${env:HOME}`

Comment: You might also find it useful to add `HOME=%USERPROFILE%` to your User Environment variables if you routinely use both Windows and Mac/Linux

Comment: I'm on Windows and I had to use `${env:UserProfile}`.

Comment: added `$env:HOME=$env:USERPROFILE` to my `$env:USERPROFILE/Documents/WindowsPowerShell/Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1` powershell profile script.

Comment: `${userHome}` should be platform-independent. See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference